# How can I get shift+arrow keys working in tmux

Tags: tmux

I tried adding the below to ~/.tmux.conf so that i could use Shift+arrow keys to jump across windows, but doesnt work.

```
bind -n S-Left  previous-window
bind -n S-Right next-window
```

This is not under vim as I saw in other qns answered in stackoverflow. Even if I tried to use this for navigating across panes it doesnt work. However, if I use the Alt+arrow keys it works like a charm.

Any way I could get the Shift+arrow mappings work?

Comment: Strange I saw quite a few configs containing this. Example: https://guide.offsecnewbie.com/kali-configuration/tmux-config

Comment: I restart the session each time since this is the only one. Restarting the computer isn’t possible since it’s a remote server.

Comment: Which terminal are you using? check if shift+ arrow is not already being used by the terminal.

Comment: @HeisAif TERM=xterm for me(via putty). Nothing realyy happens if I press Shift+Arrow(s), but how can I check if it is really mapped to something else?

Answer (score 1):

Although PuTTY sets the TERM variable to xterm, its behavior does not in fact match xterm's behavior [link](https://superuser.com/a/1265272/1149636)

There is a bug in PuTTy which causes binding of shift key to not work [link](https://superuser.com/a/1226621/1149636)

Your can switch to [KiTTy](http://www.9bis.net/kitty/#!index.md), a fork of PuTTY, which solves the problem you are facing,

Comment: Thanks @HeisAif, however I am not able to try this since our company does not allow Kitty to be downloaded. Wonder if there is any other way.